# How to dynamically plot the columns of a matrix to one another?

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

```
mat = [1,2,1;2,4,6;3,6,9];
mat =

 1     2     1
 2     4     6
 3     6     9


plot(a(:,1), a(:,2), a(:,1), a(:,3));
```

I would like to know how it is done to plot the first column of *mat* to every other column of the matrix. But I don't want to do it like above mentioned. Is there a way to do it with any matrix with variable size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
plot(a(:,1), a(:,2:end));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple for loop:

```
for i = 2:size(mat,2)
  plot(mat(:,1), mat(:,i));
  hold all
end
```